# How can I update Map keys?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how to reformat the keys of Maps. Here, I am making a new key with the same value, and deleting the old key:

```js
const beatles = new Map();

beatles.set('John', 1);
beatles.set('Paul', 2);
beatles.set('George', 3);

beatles.forEach((value, key) => {
  beatles.set(`${key} and Ringo`, value)
    .delete(key);
});


console.log(beatles); //doesn't work
```

This does not seem to work. More generally, I can't figure out the procedure for looping through maps and updating them.

Comment: I figured out I could declare a `new Map()` and set the keys and values of that. But is there any way to update the old one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Map.prototype.forEach` operates over the *live* collection - if a new key is added during one of the callbacks, that new key will be one more iteration the process has to iterate over later. You have an infinite loop.

Extract the entries, then clear the map, then iterate over the entries:

```js
const beatles = new Map();

beatles.set('John', 1);
beatles.set('Paul', 2);
beatles.set('George', 3);

const entries = [...beatles.entries()];
beatles.clear();
for (const [key, value] of entries) {
  beatles.set(`${key} and Ringo`, value);
}

console.log(beatles);

// result:
// Map(3) {"John and Ringo" => 1, "Paul and Ringo" => 2, "George and Ringo" => 3}
```

Creating a new Map would be a bit easier though.